# Creating classes by user of the program

Tags: python, class, oop, instance

How can user that is using my program create a class? For example i have this class in the program by default:

```
class OpticalDevices:
    def __init__(self,nofarticle='-',model='-')
        self.nofarticle=nofarticle
        self.model=model
```

Now user wants to add some other class, he doesn't want do add anything in OpticalDevices, he wants to add in the other class,a RamMemory for example. This class doesn't exist so he needs to create it. The name of the class is not known until this point so I can't create a class in the code directly. He entered which attributes does he want to have and the result is:

> RamMemory class
>
> nofarticle='-'
>
> model='-'
>
> speed='-'
>
> capacity='-'

How can I from this 5 strings create this and let it stay in code or if it is kept in file to load this 5 stings from file and create class:

```
class RamMemory:
    def __init__(self,nofarticle='-',ram_type='-',model='-',speed='-',capacity='-'):
        self.nofarticle=nofarticle
        self.ram_type=ram_type
        self.model=model
        self.capacity=capacity
        self.speed=speed
```

And how can I create instance of a class from a string? For example:

```
s="opticaldevice1"
```

And now i want to create this:

```
opticaldevice1=OpticalDevices()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this

```
type('RamMemory',() /*Object is base class*/, {nofarticle='-', ram_type='-',.. })
```

see
https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html
and
http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/28/improve-your-python-metaclasses-and-dynamic-classes-with-type/

Comment: That is what I have been looking for, I just didn't know how is it called, thank you! :)